# Does assigning a variable to a GET or POST for a DB query effect something?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, phpmyadmin

Title says it all,
Does asigning a GET or POST to a variable and using that information (the variable) to send information or retrieve influence the speed of the query or anything else.
Couldn't find anything on the internet.

Comment: Please provide some sample code, that title does *not* really say it all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What assigning variables does, is allocating a piece of memory and give it some value.

In theory, it IS a bit slower to assign a second variable, but I don't think you can feel the loss even in relatively big projects.